# Can I send encrypted Credit Card data to my non-PCI server for sending it to a PCI Credit Card Service? WITHOUT STORING THE DATA ON MY SERVER

Tags: pci-compliance, pci-dss

I am working with a payment gateway, which offers me a method to tokenize credit cards, should I send the cc data from the frontend or should I send the (encrypted) data to my backend and then to the payment gateway? All of this without being PCI complier.

Comment: You should do it the way the gateway you're working with tells you to do it.  Their API will have (or at least should have) been built with input from a QSA about the proper way to handle data and what the effects are on integrators' PCI status.  It also matters what keys you're using to encrypt the data.  If you add more details, you might get a more specific answer.

Comment: The encryption method is from their documentation, AES CBC 128 with a key. They don't say anything, it is just an endpoint. I want to know that if instead of making a front-end call, I can make a backend call with the same data.

Comment: What you are describing looks like you are participating in processing of sensitive card data and are looking for some form of End-2-End Encryption. Solutions like these are designed to limit the exposure you have and decrease you PCI DSS compliance requirements if implemented properly. It's a rather a 'slider' not a 'checkbox' though and you might not be completely out of scope (the more is provided by a PCI compliant party, the smaller your exposure). If possible and data comes from SRED compliant payment terminals, using PCI P2PE from the PSP would help you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Roman, If your processor has a way to send the data from the front end, this will almost always be the best choice so that you do not have to worry about possibly sending raw card information through your backend. Encryption can be tricky. If you have a public key, you are going to have to mess with that in your JavaScript before posting back to your server. If you post the raw card information back to your server, you are automatically in higher PCI scope. We integrate with a company called USIO and they have the client side tools either with a Iframe popup or embedding the fields in your page to get that sensitive information. It’s pretty easy to use and it keeps the PCI scope down for us.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand and agree with you. I just want to know if in case everything goes ok and I can encrypt the data, if sending the encrypted data to my server (without storing it) makes me fall inside PCI scope.

Comment: If the data is encrypted before you send it to your servers, then it does not increase your PCI scope.